# Angular Universal + Firebase cloud functions deployment issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I've been stuck on this issue for some time now.
My Angular project version is **9.0.3**.
The @angular/fire version is **6.1.4**

I have followed the guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md)
The project builds and renders for the local Express server I have.
The problem occurs when I deploy the project to Firebase with a cloud function that will render the application.
Running the command `ng deploy` gives the below error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/teebo/Development/motf/dist/motif/browser/index.html'
```

This issue is linked to a reported issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2765)

I have investigated and found that in the project's dist folder, a `index.original.html` file is generated instead of `index.html`.

I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2847) with no feedback from the maintainers.
If there is anything I am missing or there's something I can do to circumvent this issue, please share and any suggestions are appreciated.
Any suggestion, comment, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to circumvent this issue.
This is not a proper solution for the `ng deploy` issue but at least I can deploy the ssr function.

Because my dist folder is nested in another dist folder (Which does not include the `browser` build folder), that is why I was getting the error when running `ng deploy`. Below are steps I've followed to at least be able to deploy.

1. Run `ng deploy` (It will error out with the above error but will build the app and create a dist folder).
2. Copy the browser folder to the dist folder that does not have it (In my case I have copied it to a dist folder one level up).
3. Deploy the ssr function by running `firebase deploy --only functions:ssr` (You can change `functions:ssr` to whatever name you have named your function).

This worked for me;
It would save time to write an npm script to do all this but then; I am not sure if my firebase/universal config is wrong or there is a bug with `@angular/fire`.